# Is it possible to wrap characters around text every time you paste something from the system clipboard?

Tags: insert-mode, os-clipboard

I am going to be pasting a lot of characters into a file. Each time I paste something, the pasted element will need to be wrapped in quotes and followed by a comma. Is there a way to automatically wrap these characters after each paste in vim? The paste will be coming from the system clipboard, not a vim paste buffer.

For example, say the system clipboard contains `a`, when pasting this into vim using a middle-click, I would like it to insert `"a",`.

Answer (score 7):

Do you need to use the mouse (middle-klick)? I'd go for a macro:

1. Press <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to start recording
2. Press <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>`</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to first insert the first set of quote, then paste from the system clipboard, go to the end of the paste and append quote and comma
3. Press <kbd>q</kbd> to stop recording

Then, each time you want to paste that way, simply hit <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

Note: If you're on X, you might need to use <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> instead of <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>, dpending on which clipboard you really want to use. See `:h x11-selection`.

Note2: This pastes before your cursor. Change the first <kbd>i</kbd> to <kbd>a</kbd> to paste after your cursor.

Comment: When using _the same_ macro often (without using other macros inbetween), it's very convenient to use `@@` from the 2nd time on.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your vim includes clipboard support (`:version` shows `+clipboard`) and you intend to do this in more than one editing session, I would recommend creating a mapping that does this for you:

```
nnoremap <F5> i"",<Esc>h"+P
```

`<F5>`: what you'll hit to trigger the mapping. Could be any combination of keys.

`i"",<Esc>`: `"",` and escape insert mode.

`h`: move the cursor left 1 character.

`"+P`: paste from the system clipboard before the current character. If pasting via middle-click, you'd want "*P instead

This is currently formulated to work when in normal mode, but could work in insert mode by removing the leading `i` (and perhaps adding one at the end)

Answer (score 4):

My [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) provides a `g,"p` mapping that pastes each line in the register (prepend `"+` for the system clipboard, as usual) surrounded by double quotes and delimited by commas, all in one line. This is just one particular variant from a plethora of similar mappings; some even query for the separator.